# Calling javascript function with php code

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to call the Javascript function declared at the top in my php area. However its not working. Can anyone tell me the reason for it. Everything else is working except for this part. Please help me.

```
  <!doctype HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>AES (Rijndael) Encryption Test in JavaScript</title>
  <script src="aes-enc.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
  <script src="aes-dec.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
  <script src="aes-test.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function doDecryption()
            {
            document.write("Inside Javascript");
            var ct, key;

  ct = hex2s(<?php echo $myValue; ?>);
  document.write("Inside Javascript");
  document.write(ct);
 // key = hex2s(theForm.key.value);
 // theForm.plaintext.value = byteArrayToHex(rijndaelDecrypt(ct, key, "ECB"));


            }


  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("encryption") or die(mysql_error());
  $userId = $_POST['userId'];


  if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && ($_POST['key'] == ""))
  {
     $query = mysql_query("select * from employee_details where id = '$userId'");                       if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    foreach($row as $value)
                    echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

            else { echo "No rows returned"; }}
    else if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && ($_POST['key']))
        {

           $columname = "ciphertext";
           $tablename = "employee_details";



                function getField($field, $tbl_name, $condition)
            {

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT $field FROM $tbl_name WHERE id =  ".$condition);

                 return @mysql_result($result, 0);
            }

                $myValue = getField($columname,$tablename,$userId);

                echo "$myValue";
                [B]echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    doDecryption();
                    </script>';[/B]
                echo "whats happening";
                //doDecryption();

        }

   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: I figured out why this is failing after running the code in my head. It would have been rather easier to solve if you had provided error messages. For that matter, as a rule of thumb, try to break your question down into either "Why doesn't this JS work?" or "Why doesn't this PHP output this HTML/JS source code?" instead of "Why doesn't the HTML/JS source code generated by PHP not do what I expect?"

Comment: **DANGER** : You have an SQL Injection Security Vulnerability! Do not build SQL queries by sticking together strings that include unsanitized `$_POST` data! http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @David: Wow, I didn't know that they even made a site for Little Bobby Tables (can't access it, though ): ).

Comment: There are several, that's one of the better ones. Unfortunately, it does seem to have fallen over since I made my previous comment. No doubt it will back back up before long. It explains the issues and how to avoid them in a number of different languages (generally by explaining the various methods of using parametrized queries)

Comment: In the mean time, there is the Google cache of the PHP page: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ib1peGZMTNoJ:bobby-tables.com/php.html+bobby+tables&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Answer (score 5):

`$myValue` doesn't have a value when you try to use it in the JS.

The PHP runs on the server, outputs an HTML document with embedded JavaScript, the document is sent to the client and then the JavaScript runs.

If you don't know what value the JavaScript variable needs to have until the PHP gets to the end of the document, then you can't generate that part of the JS until then. You probably want to write it as an argument to the function call instead.

Once you do that you have another problem — if your data is a string, then it needs to be quoted (and any matching quote marks inside it need to be escaped).

In a nutshell: **PHP outputs text that might be processed as JS, it cannot call JavaScript functions** (unless you start mixing extensions that can talk to Rhino/Spidermonkey/etc on the server).

All that said, in this case, there doesn't seem to be any reason to use JavaScript in the first place and you would be better off moving all the logic to PHP.

Incidentally, your choice of Doctype will trigger Quirks mode in most browsers. This is almost always highly undesirable.

A better choice would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Or if you really want Transitional:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: David, How about this one [code]echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    doDecryption("'.$myValue.'");
    </script>';[/code]      & then in the javascript [code]function doDecryption(param){ct = hex2s(param);
      document.println("Inside Javascript");
      document.write(ct);}[/code]   This doesn't work either...Gets hte same result

Comment: See my first comment on the question. Figure out what the JS should look like, and then figure out how to get the PHP to generate that. It's really hard to tell if a given bit of PHP will work (especially when it is outputting unknown data).

Answer (score 2):

Change you javascript function to take a parameter (*the value of `$myValue`*)

```
function doDecryption(param)
```

Then change the `ct = hex2s(<?php echo $myValue; ?>);` to `ct = hex2s(param);`

Last, you need to pass the `$myValue` php variable to the javsacript function function and you can do this when you call it

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                doDecryption( '.$myValue;.');
                </script>';
```

if you `$myValue` variable is a stirng, then you should add quotes around it when feeding it to javascript

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                doDecryption( "'.$myValue;.'");
                </script>';
```

Comment: Same output I am getting Gaby... This one... 6743c3d1519ab4f2cd9a78ab09a511bdwhats happening   :(  any other alternative?

Comment: @user527696, i had extra parenthesis in the echoed scripts .. try with the change i made.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify the question? If the question is: can you call a client side javascript function, at runtime in your server side PHP code? the answer is no.

if you ran a nodeJS server it's possible to host the javascript server side and execute the function calls as long as the javascript code resides somewhere that nodejs can execute it.

Overall though, the use case is confusing to me.  I am guessing that an application that was originally designed to do decryption client side in the browser does so because the server does not have the keys to perform the decryption.  So if this was an application that someone else wrote and you are trying to make changes to, you will want to make sure that you actually have the keys you need server side to perform the decryption process, since it was probably never intended for the server to have access to the decryption keys.  Additionally, if the server does have access to the keys to perform the decryption, there is probably a nice way to do this with php code. (I'm not a php dev, so I can't speak to exactly what php code you would need to write the decryption php script).

Hope this helps.
Mark

Comment: Nevemind. I didnt see the script tags you had in the php code. So this post is irrelevant to your problem. Sorry.

Comment: Was about to tell you that too ;) Please don't try to answer faster than the other. If you answer is correct and well written, you'll have upvote and maybe an accepted one.

Comment: Well regarding the output, I removed some of the php code in the program so as to make the code shorter. Now I am getting the output of the PHP code desired but when I am calling the javascript function, the javascript function is not being called...In other words the first print statement inside the javascript is not being printed at all...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333563/calling-javascript-function-with-php-code-not-working   I have posted the whole program again here..Sorry for the Inconvenience .. The code posted above is working fine for me but not when I am adding the php functionality to it. I am able to get the php result but not the part in javascript..

Answer (score -1):

It looks well if you are not using AJAX (if you are may be you need to eval() your response)

I have tried a shorted version of your code and it is working fine.

```
<!doctype HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>AES (Rijndael) Encryption Test in JavaScript</title>
<script src="aes-enc.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script src="aes-dec.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script src="aes-test.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doDecryption()
{
    document.write("Inside Javascript");
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    doDecryption();
    </script>';
    echo "whats happening";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result is

```
Inside Javascriptwhats happening
```

HTH, Regards.

Comment: Since you removed the PHP sections, and the problem was that the PHP was outputting bad data … that isn't a surprise.

Comment: You don't answer his question since : 1- you don't use his variables which is his problem right now (see David's answer) 2- the OP doesn't mention AJAX (and his question either) why mention it here ? 3- `eval()` seriously? (May want to downvote that.)

Comment: Right @David Dorward but he ask about why the JS was not called, and it is acctaully, if the rest o the code is ok... and without error, output or any more clue.

Comment: OK guys, thanks for your superiority :) just trying to give a hand. I did not say anything...

Comment: Guys I am not understanding what you are trying to so.. Can you please be more specific. I will answer any questions that you have..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333563/calling-javascript-function-with-php-code-not-working   I have posted the whole program again here..Sorry for the Inconvenience .. The code posted above is working fine for me but not when I am adding the php functionality to it. I am able to get the php result but not the part in javascript..